# Prevent typingAttributes in UITextview automatically resets?

Tags: ios, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I am trying to implement a rich text editor with some key word highlight feature.
I implemented the UITextviewDelegate in my own class, and changed the `attributedText` using my predefined styles in

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text;
```

And, I reseted the `typingAttributes` whenever I changed the`attributedText`, or the selected range was changed.

It works fine. But if I enabled the `autocapitalizationType` and `autocorrectionType`, the app  hangs or crashes when autocorrect view appears. I debugged the source, found the the root cause is the method 'setTypingAttributes:' hangs too much.  Document says : `@property(nonatomic,copy) NSDictionary *typingAttributes NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0); // automatically resets when the selection changes`

Are there any ways to prevent it change?